# PostgreSQL query group by two "parameters"

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

I've been trying to figure out the following PostgreSQL query with no success for two days now.

Let's say I have the following table:

```
| date         | value  |
-------------------------
| 2018-05-11   |  0.20  |
| 2018-05-11   | -0.12  |
| 2018-05-11   |  0.15  |
| 2018-05-10   | -1.20  |
| 2018-05-10   | -0.70  |
| 2018-05-10   | -0.16  |
| 2018-05-10   |  0.07  |
```

And I need to find out the query to count positive and negative values per day:

```
| date         | positives  | negatives  |
------------------------------------------
| 2018-05-11   | 2          | 1          |
| 2018-05-10   | 1          | 3          |
```

I've been able to figure out the query to extract only positives or negatives, but not both at the same time:

```
SELECT to_char(table.date, 'DD/MM') AS date
      COUNT(*)                     AS negative
FROM table
WHERE table.date >= DATE(NOW() - '20 days' :: INTERVAL) AND
      value < '0'
GROUP BY to_char(date, 'DD/MM'), table.date
ORDER BY table.date DESC;
```

Can please someone assist? This is driving me mad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
select date_trunc('day', t.date) as dte, 
       sum( (value < 0)::int ) as negatives,
       sum( (value > 0)::int ) as positives
from t
where t.date >= current_date - interval '20 days' 
group by date_trunc('day', t.date),
order by dte desc;
```

Notes:

- I prefer using `date_trunc()` to casting to a string for removing the time component.
- You don't need to use `now()` and convert to a date.  You can just use `current_date`.
- Converting a string to an interval seems awkward, when you can specify an interval using the `interval` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-expressions.html) clause with the aggregate function.

```
SELECT to_char(table.date, 'DD/MM') AS date,
      COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE value < 0) AS negative,
      COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE value > 0) AS positive
FROM table
WHERE table.date >= DATE(NOW() - '20 days'::INTERVAL)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY DATE(table.date) DESC
```